# window.ethereum returning undefined when using my chrome extension

Tags: web3js

When i'm in browser and do console.log(window.ethereum), it returns an object.
However, when I use my chrome extension and do console.log(window.ethereum), it returns undefined. My code:

```
const createMetaMaskProvider = require('metamask-extension-provider')
const Web3 = require('web3')

const web3Provider = createMetaMaskProvider()
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider)

console.log(window.ethereum)
```

The declaration stuff is irrelevant, but thought i'd still put there.
I am also doing this on a website where I've already got my wallet connected (OpenSea), so it's not an issue with connecting my wallet